# Order a data frame using character and numeric columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe:

```
 df <- data.frame(c(name = "FORT DUNCAN", "DETAR HOSPITAL", "CYPRESS FAIRBANKS","MISSION REGIONAL", "Test"), rate = c(8.0,8.7,8.7,8.1,8.9))
colnames(df) = c("name","rate")
ordered_df <- df[order(df[,2]),]

               name rate
1       FORT DUNCAN  8.0
4  MISSION REGIONAL  8.1
2    DETAR HOSPITAL  8.7
3 CYPRESS FAIRBANKS  8.7
5              Test  8.9
```

I can clearly order the dataframe by the rate variable. However, If two rates are similar then I want to order by name. i.e. Detar Hospital and Cypress Fairbanks have the same rate of 8.7. Therefore, I want Cypress Fairbanks to move up and Detar Hospital to move down and Test should remain at its place (The last place according to the rate)...
Any ideas???

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `order` accepts many variables via `...` you can do the following:

```
> df[order(df[,2],df[,1] ),]
               name rate
1       FORT DUNCAN  8.0
4  MISSION REGIONAL  8.1
3 CYPRESS FAIRBANKS  8.7
2    DETAR HOSPITAL  8.7
5              Test  8.9
```

Comment: This is a really good answer but it does not work if in rate you have values "10.1, 10.3, 9.9", because the "10.1" is ordered before the 9.9. I cannot find a way around it.

Comment: @efrem (probably you have a character rate, that is no good and different from the example, anyway `df[order(as.numeric(df[,2]), df[,1]), ]`)

Answer (score 3):

I think I fixed it by:

```
ordered_df <- df[order(df$rate, df$name),]
```

Cheers